Why does Tweedie Deviance not contain the dispersion parameter?
I was looking at the tweedie deviance function, and I noticed it only seems to contain the parameters for the mean and the power parameter.
But intuitively, I would think the dispersion parameter would be important here. Does anyone have any intuition behind why it can be dropped?
Particularly for the compound Poisson Gamma distribution where 1 < p < 2.
Thanks for any help or info!

According to documentation :
Loglikelihood function not implemented because of the complexity of calculating an infinite series of summations. The variance power can be estimated using the estimate_tweedie_power function that is part of the statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM class.
Dispersion is calulated with Loglikelihood.
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Tweedie.html
